# application design, object oriented not desirable?

Tags: oop

Long post ahead.

I have to write a business application and I came to a conclusion that conventional way of doing this is a poor choice. I will expose here my point of view and would like to hear some opinions, and critics, or, inversely, some confirmation of my thoughts.

**CONTEXT**:

A Company sells some highly complex financial contracts. External Clients contact this company in order to ask for a price. They provide a set of parameters of the product they wish, this is used to make a Price. The provided parameters are not totally explicit: clients usually buys a specific product, so a very large number of parameters is implicit, and only known by the Salesman who is in charge of this particular Client for this particular Country.

The salesman wants to automate the pricing process. Obviously, his knowledge is the only way for me to rightly make a request for Price, because of all implicit parameters for each specific client, and each specific Salesman. From the Sales side, all Financial Products are categorized by their Family. From the IT side, there is only a huge flat list of all possible parameters, and a certain combination of them makes what a Salesman calls "Product A" or "Product B".

The application is supposed to map Salesman perspective into IT perspective and give back a price.

**EXTENDING AN EXISTING SOLUTION:**

Product Families are pretty good proxies for Object Hierarchies and inherit from each other. A large number of parameters are set by default, or overridden in child classes. The problem is however, the class' methods are not only dependent on the number of parameters, or their types, but also dependent on some commercial logic, like the specific Salesman, specific Client (that's the whole point), or Country. Obviously, Clients and Salesmen can be added or removed quickly, so it is highly desirable to also 'parametrize' this. Here is an example of how this would look like (at least, how I imagine it):

```
class AbstractProduct:
    pass

class ProductA(AbstractProduct):
    def __init__(self, a,b, ... z, client_name=None, sales_name=None ...):
        self.a=a
        # ....


    def make_a_price(self):
        if self.sales_name == "A.J" and self.client_name="Homer.S":
            request = {
                "a":self.a,
                "b":self.b,
                "c": 23,
                "d":"blah"
            }
        elif self.sales_name =="B.J" :
            request = {
                "a": self.a,
                "b": self.b,
                "c": 23,
                "d": "tom",
                "e":"dummy",
                "f":"dummy"
            }
        else:
            request = {
                "K":42
            }
        # ...
        # ...
        request["common_parameter1"]="a"
        request["common_parameter2"]="b"
        # ...

        price = send_request_for_price()
        return price
```

**ISSUES:**

It seems to me that mixing any kind of commercial logic inside the price-requesting logic is nonsense because:

- I need updating my code base for any kind of commercial reason
- I do not hold any domain knowledge, so I might break something for a product, or a client while modifying a feature for another client... I cannot guarantee that there is no regression (extensive testing is required)
- Once again, I do not hold any domain knowledge, so I cannot draw any conclusion for inheritance or composition relationships between objects.
- Adding `if` statements to check for Salesman / Client / Country whatever is silly
- I could create a bunch of factories, but this only moves complexity higher: I would end up dealing with commercial cases at the Object level, instead of variables level.
- Well, just because commercial logic (country/sales/client-specific implicit parameters) has nothing to do with pricing.

**PROPOSED SOLUTION:**

A 'Product' is just a set of parameters, some of them are constant within a commercial scope (for a particular client/country/..), and some of them are free (Free +  Constant = entire Univers). So let's store in a database all constant parameters with a commercial scope as primary key.

All free parameters left must have a function which returns exactly this parameter as result. Store these functions names in the database too. These functions are composed of other functions etc... and so recursively, until all composed functions are decomposed into 'atomic functions' which takes only variables, or None as parameters (no other functions), and can have validation functions (predicates, which only return True / False, so that the parameter is in a good format). Store all of those functions and their parameters names in the database.

Write an 'Evaluator' which, for a given commercial scope, reads from the database a sequence of constant parameters and set them into price request; as well as a list of the functions to run in order to set Free parameters. This Evaluator breaks down composed functions into atomic once, and recursivly calls them within the context. Validation functions are run before each atomic function (if there is any)

**What does this buys me?:**

- I can guarantee that there are no regressions since each function is 'unique' and attached to an ID in my database (no code sharing through inheritance or composition)
- No business logic in my code
- Straightforward implementation (at least, in my opinion): each function is completely independent, and Evaluator is 30 lines long (not counting SQL requests)
- If a new commercial rule is introduced or replaced, I just need to re-point my database entry to another function
- I can add new parameters to functions, and new format-validating functions for each parameter as simply as adding rows in my database.

So... profit?

Comment: In general, I reject the notion of object-oriented domain models in information systems, and your argument seems to point in the same direction. However, I think OOP is useful for constructing complex systems in terms of communicating state machines. Business entities generally have no responsibilities in the solution system, information systems aren't business simulations. Perhaps you should look at your Evaluator (and the features that communicate with it) as the actors in your system.

Comment: Could you please point me to a PDF / book which would explain your point better? I am not sure how to relate the term 'communicating state machines' in my context ...

Comment: See the [actor model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). I'm basically saying that OOP is for modeling computational systems (the solution), not for modeling data (the problem domain). GUIs, report-writers, sockets, file-system API's, DBMSs, and perhaps your Evaluator, are examples of good objects / state machines. Things like Products and Clients are the subjects of facts (relations) which should be held in objects (state) and communicated between objects (messages), not conflated with objects.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is extremely important to discuss issues like yours, therefore I quickly answer before it is closed as opinion based :)

The most revealing point you make, and the reason your argument is flawed in my opinion is: **you are not a domain expert**.

This may not be just my opinion, since [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) is based on the very idea that we developers need to understand the domain first, before we write any kind of code. Using the same language the business uses (ubiquitous language) not just to speak about our software, but inside as well.

This idea is far from new. In the early days of software development, developers were basically domain experts who have taken on development tasks as well.

I know, finding a "quick" technical solution is easier on the short term. You don't even have to understand exactly why it's needed, it's just passed as requirements, so whatever, right? But I think this exactly makes IT a "cost center", and not a partner.

So, if by "conventional way" you mean putting business logic in code, then yes, that's still our goal I would hope. If however you have a concrete problem with an existing design I suggest you post that question again, with some more detail.

Comment: But the point is, I cannot afford to become a domain expert in 3 weeks time, while the project is supposed to be a "quick proof of concept" :/ ...

Comment: Welcome to our industry :) The next step is usually to put the "proof of concept" into production. :)

Comment: So, as a hypothetical Team Leader in my team, you wouldn't allow my kind of solution?

Comment: I don't know enough about the exact circumstances to make such judgment. On the long term I would however aim to build up expert knowledge and adapt the architecture to match the knowledge gained.